# Insert contents of a file against a pattern using sed

Tags: shell, sed, grep

I want to insert contents of a file after a pattern matches. I have tried the following command but it didn't work

```
sed '/ghi\(\)/ r file2.txt' file1.txt
```

The contents of file1.txt are:

```
abc
def
ghi()
jkl
```

The contents of file2.txt are:

```
hello world!
my name is xyz
i live in abc city
```

The desired output : I want the content of file1.txt to become:

```
abc
def
ghi()
hello world!
my name is xyz
i live in abc city
jkl
```

Am I missing any parameter? How to achieve this?

Comment: `sed --version`?

Comment: What didn't work? What is the exact error?

Comment: I see the desired output on console but content doesn't get inserted in the actual file i.e file1. File1 remains unchanged. N the file has write permissions because other content gets inserted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need `-i` to make replacement `in place`, and you can also use `.bak` to make a `.bak` backup file

```
sed -i.bak '/ghi\(\)/ r file2.txt' file1.txt
```

it will change file1.txt content and create `file1.txt.bak` for backup

Answer (score 0):

you could run following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '/ghi()/{print;system("cat file2.txt");next} 1' file1.txt
```

---

Also following `sed` too worked fine for me, I have GNU `sed` 4.2.1

```
sed '/ghi()/r file2.txt' file1.txt
```

Comment: Can you read my above comment on what the priblem is and suggest something?